# oracle sql join not correct

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to sum two tables. Both tables contain the number of rowas grouped by a category:

```
number    category
5          A
4819       B
1          C

number    category
12043      B
```

I tried the following:

```
select a.category, a.number + b.number as number
from  a
right join  b
    on a.category = b.category
```

I get:

```
number     category
4          16862
```

I don't understand why I don't get all three categories. I trief left join instead of right join.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with you right join is that `a` table should appear on the *right* side of the join.  Or, using a left join, we could write:

```
SELECT
    a.category,
    a.number + COALESCE(b.number, 0) AS number
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b
    ON a.category = b.category;
```

But this answer assumes that the `a` table would contain every category which you want to appear in your result set.  For a more general solution, we might have to use a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.category, b.category) AS category,
    COALESCE(a.number, 0) + COALESCE(b.number, 0) AS number
FROM tablea a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableb b
    ON a.category = b.category;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select category ,sum(number) value 
from (
    select category, number from tablea
    union all select category, number from tableb
)
group by category
```

Another option is to do a `full outer join`: this would allow values coming from both sides of the join:

```
select 
    coalesce(ta.category, tb.category) number,
    sum(coalesce(ta.number, 0) + coalesce(tb.number, 0)) value
from tablea ta 
full outer join tableb tb on ta.category = tb.category 
group by coalesce(ta.category , tb.category )
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used nvl(). This works:

```
select a.category, nvl(a.number, 0) + nvl(b.number, 0) as number
from  a
right join  b
    on a.category = b.category
```

Comment: This won't produce your desired output from your posted data for the reason @TimBielgeleisen states: you're using a RIGHT JOIN when you should be using a LEFT JOIN.